# Why does my bash script flag this awk substring command as a syntactic error when it works in the terminal?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to extract a list of dates from a series of links using lynx's dump function and piping the output through grep and awk. This operation works successfully in the terminal and outputs dates accurately. However, when it is placed into a shell script, bash claims a syntax error:

```
Scripts/ETC/PreD.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Scripts/ETC/PreD.sh: line 18: ` lynx --dump "$link" | grep -m 1 Date | awk '{print substr($0,10)}' >> dates.txt'
```

For context, this is part of a while-read loop in which $link is being read from a file. Operations undertaken inside this while-loop when the awk command is removed are all successful, as are similar while-loops that include other awk commands.

I know that either I'm misunderstanding how bash handles variable substitution, or how bash handles awk commands, or some combination of the two. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

EDIT: Shellcheck is divided on this, the website version finds no error, but my downloaded version provides error SC1083, which says:

```
This { is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.
```

A check on the Shellcheck GitHub page provides this:

```
This error is harmless when the curly brackets are supposed to be literal, in e.g. awk {'print $1'}. 
However, it's cleaner and less error prone to simply include them inside the quotes: awk '{print $1}'.
```

Script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -u 4 link
do
        IFS=/ read a b c d e <<< "$link"
        echo "$e" >> 1.txt
        lynx --dump "$link" | grep -A 1 -e With: | tr -d [:cntrl:][:digit:][] | sed 's/\With//g' | awk '{print substr($0,10)}' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1'\ and'/' | tr -s ' ' >> 2.txt
        lynx --dump "$link" | grep -m 1 Date | awk '{print substr($0,10)}' >> dates.txt
done 4< links.txt
```

Comment: error does not seems to be in `awk` , you should put your script in shellcheck.net to get the syntax error. Also, using `grep` and `awk` in same line is redundant,

Comment: You need to post the script if you want help debugging it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `tr -d [:cntrl:][:digit:][]` (especially that `[]` at the end and no quotes around the script)? What are you trying to do with `sed 's/\(.*\),/\1'\ and'/'`? Post a FULL minimal script that produces the error message - we can't even see the shebang in the snippet you posted.

Comment: What shell did you use in shelcheck?  Did you use the right shebang?

Comment: The problem could be in any of the 3 programs in the long pipe. Notice the `length` variable in `awk` script is always 0.

Comment: The shellcheck error message you post doesn't seem to be from the code you posted.

Comment: @DudiBoy unfortunately POSIX allows the `length()` function to be called not only without arguments but without even parens so you can write `length` and it means the same as `length($0)`. Horrible and I personally would never do that, but we're stuck with it. In the OPs code it makes no sense to be present at all in that `substr($0,10,length)` as it'll be a larger value that can be present after the starting index of 10 - `substr($0,10)` is more concise and semantically better.

Comment: The code listed here has problems, but should not cause the error listed. My guess is that there's a quoting problem earlier in the script (in one of the 12 omitted lines before the quoted section) that's causing a chain parsing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `sed` command you have unmatched `'`, due to unquoted `'`.
2. In `awk` script your have constant zero `length` variable.

From [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

> substr(string, start [, length ])
>
> Return a length-character-long substring of string, starting at character number start. The first character of a string is character
>   number one.48 For example, substr("washington", 5, 3) returns "ing".
>
> If length is not present, substr() returns the whole suffix of string that begins at character number start. For example,
>   substr("washington", 5) returns "ington". The whole suffix is also
>   returned if length is greater than the number of characters remaining
>   in the string, counting from character start.
>
> If start is less than one, substr() treats it as if it was one. (POSIX doesn’t specify what to do in this case: BWK awk acts this way,
>   and therefore gawk does too.) If start is greater than the number of
>   characters in the string, substr() returns the null string. Similarly,
>   **if length is present but less than or equal to zero, the null string
>   is returned.**

Also I suggest you combine `grep|awk|sed|tr` into single awk script. And debug the awk script with printouts.

From:

```
lynx --dump "$link" | grep -A 1 -e With: | tr -d [:cntrl:][:digit:][] | sed 's/\With//g' | awk '{print substr($0,10,length)}' | sed 's/\(.*\),/\1'\ and'/' | tr -s ' ' >> 2.txt
```

To:

```
lynx --dump "$link" | awk '/With/{found=1;next}found{found=0;print sub(/\(.*\),/,"& and",gsub(/ +/," ",substr($0,10)))}' >> 2.txt
```

From:

```
lynx --dump "$link" | grep -m 1 Date | awk '{print substr($0,10,length)}' >> dates.txt
```

To:

```
lynx --dump "$link" | awk '/Date/{print substr($0,10)}' >> dates.txt
```